# Configuring Orbit slider - advanced section

Tags: slideshow, carousel, orbit

In the Zurb Foundation docs the section on Advanced of Configuring Orbit there are settings you can use like this one "animation_speed:1500;" and its obvious how to use them with the data-options parameter and what they do but what I dont get is options like " bullets_container_class: 'orbit-bullets'". I don't know what to do with this, if I add it to the data-options what does it do and how do I use it to modify the behavior of  the Orbit Slider?

Answer (score 0):

It appears its there so that you can rename the class for individual sliders. For example, if you have a number of sliders but want to target the bullets_container_class of just one you can change the class name in the data-options parameter in your html and target just that slider's bullet container. Not sure if this is the exact purpose, but its the only purpose I can see for listing it as a control parameter.